# Return deque-array c++

Tags: c++, deque, arraydeque

How do I return an deque  array in c++?

```
private:
   deque<int> iHouses[3];

public:
   deque<int> getHouses();
```

//gives me an error when implementing the function of course - but where should I put the brackets?

```
 deque<int> GameEngine::getHouses() {
    return this->iHouses;
}
```

Comment: Just like you return an array of anything else: you can't. There aren't special rules for array of deque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the std::array

```
#include <array>
    ....
private:
    using my_house_cont = std::array<std::deque<int>, 3>;
    my_house_cont m_houses;

public:
    my_house_cont getHouses();
```